# How to split data based on its position (i.e., payload[0]=='H') in a DAT file and set it to a variable?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I have data from a DAT file:

H 4561278 SFFJKE 12650 123091209329341             1234211223  134324409

Where at position 0 = H, position 2 = 4------ and so forth.

I want to assign position 0 (fixed length 1) the variable name record_id, position 2 (fixed length of 7) the variable name record_code

I unfortunately do not know how to implement this in the Set Variable flow connector in Mulesoft.

If you know how to do this I would greatly appreciate any advice!

Comment: What do you mean by "set a condition where per position define a variable"? Do you want to set certain letters in your string as new variables based on there position?

Comment: I see the data has some kind of separator (space, tab or something). You may want to do a splitBy and then access the output array with the positions. If the data has fixed positions instead of separators, please add more info to the post.

Comment: @JorgeGarcia I have added more context. The record or line of data is extensive maybe 400-600 positions. There are alot of empty spaces between each set up data.

Comment: @HarshankBansal I have added more context. I want to consider the whole segment of data at its respective position and fixed length and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different parsing alternatives:

**Using Flat File Schemas**

You can change the mime-type of the payload injecting a schema that will DataWeave automatically understand the format.

In the XML you can put something like this (instead of the string in `value` you just put `payload`):

```
<set-payload value='#["H 4561278 SFFJKE 12650 123091209329341 1234211223 134324409"]' mimeType="text/flatfile; schemapath=record.ffl; segmentident=ROW; recordparsing=singleRecord"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- payload]"/>
```

The `record.ffl` file looks like this (put it in the resources folder):

```
form: FLATFILE
segments:
- id: 'ROW'
  name: Some Name
  values:
   - { name: 'record_id', type: String, length: 1 }
   - { name: '_filler1', type: String, length: 1 }
   - { name: 'record_code', type: String, length: 7 }
   - { name: '_filler2', type: String, length: 1 }
   - { name: 'field3', type: String, length: 6 }
   - { name: '_filler3', type: String, length: 1 }
   - { name: 'field4', type: String, length: 5 }
   - { name: '_filler4', type: String, length: 1 }
   - { name: 'field5', type: String, length: 15 }
   - { name: '_filler5', type: String, length: 1 }
   - { name: 'field6', type: String, length: 10 }
   - { name: '_filler6', type: String, length: 1 }
   - { name: 'field7', type: String, length: 9 }
```

If you run that, you will see in the logs a representation of the message in JSON.

**Using splitBy()**

In this case you are parsing it with DataWeave in a manual way using the splitBy() function.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var row = "H 4561278 SFFJKE 12650 123091209329341 1234211223 134324409"
var splitedRow = row splitBy  " "
---
{
    record_id: splitedRow[0],
    record_code: splitedRow[1],
    field_3: splitedRow[2],
    ...
}
```

**Extracting substring from the payload**

This is the approach mentioned by @Harshank Bansal, but you can do all in one script similar to the splitBy option:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var row = "H 4561278 SFFJKE 12650 123091209329341 1234211223 134324409"
---
{
    record_id: row[0],
    record_code: row[2 to 8],
    field_3: row[10 to 15],
    ...
}
```

--- EDITED ---

**Multiline record parsing**

This technique can be used to parse multiple records with different structures. It also support parsing multiline segments, like groups, if you consume from the trail multiple elements istead of just one (`trail[0]`). If this is the case, you will call the parse function with `trail[n to -1]` where `n > 1`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = "H 4561278 SFFJKE 12650 123091209329341 1234211223 134324409/nG 1234 5678"

fun parseH(col, trail) = 
    parse(col + 
       {"record_id": trail[0][0],
        "record_code": trail[0][2 to 8],
        "record_code": trail[0][10 to 15], ...
       }
       , trail[1 to -1])
fun parseG(col, trail) =
    parse(col + 
       {"record_id": trail[0][0],
        "record_code": trail[0][2 to 8], ...
       }
       , trail[1 to -1])

fun parse(col, trail) =
    if(isEmpty(trail))
        col
    else if(trail[0] startsWith "H") 
        parseH(col, trail)
    else if(trail[0] startsWith "G")
        parseG(col, trail)
    else "error"

---
parse([],splitBy(data,"\n"))
```

Comment: the "Extracting substring from the payload" method is almost exactly what I am looking for. Just need help with one more thing please. How do I set the "var row = *** " to an array that goes through the data file. The data is differentin each record file.

Comment: @Allen I added something that may help with what you need

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your payload is the string `H 4561278 SFFJKE 12650 123091209329341 1234211223 134324409` 
You can add two `set-variable` components in your flow.

1. With variable name = `record_id` which will be equal to `payload[0]`
2. With variable name = `record_code` which will be equal to `payload[2 to 8]`

```xml
<set-variable value="#[payload[0]]" variableName="record_id" doc:name="Set record_id" doc:id="31398e49-bb98-461b-a0dc-c16eeffdd6e7" />
<set-variable value="#[payload[2 to 8]]" variableName="record_code" doc:name="Set record_code" doc:id="995a747d-9390-4a46-b22c-dc7fde110d30" />
```